# Post confirmation trigger - when user regustration is confirmed make folder in S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-cognito

Can anyone have any idea regarding this 
My task is when a user registers himself the lambda function is triggered and it makes a folder in S3 bucket with his/her name.

I can fetch the username from my user pool through Boto3 but when I am going to make a folder inside the s3 bucket it gives me the error

Please give me the advice or the possible suggestions to make it happen.

here is my python code to make s3 bucket it works also how when trying to pass the username in the condition it gives the error

```
import json
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):
# TODO implement
client = boto3.client('cognito-idp')
response = client.list_users(
UserPoolId='us-east-1_EVPcl4p64',
 AttributesToGet = [
    "userName"
    ]

)

s3 = boto3.client('s3')

bucket_name = "demoupload1"

folder_name = "userName"



if (AttributesToGet) {
    s3.put_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=(folder_name+'/'))
}
```

This is the same I am trying through Node js also this also gives me an error

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var s3Client = new AWS.S3();


/*global fileContent*/
exports.handler = function(event, context) {
console.log(event.userName);
if (event.userName) {
    var params = { Bucket: 'demoupload1', Key: 'userName/'};
}


s3Client.upload(params, function (err, data) {
if (err) {
    console.log("Error creating the folder: ", err);
    } else {
    console.log("Successfully created a folder on S3");

}
});        




};
```

PS - I am a newbie to AWS lambda 
any kind of help is really appreciated

Comment: What's the error? Can you provide full error msg?

Comment: Response:
{
  "errorType": "Error",
  "errorMessage": "params.Body is required",
  "trace": [
    "Error: params.Body is required",
    "    at ManagedUpload.validateBody (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/s3/managed_upload.js:271:13)",
   
  ]
}

Comment: "    at ManagedUpload.configure (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/s3/managed_upload.js:123:10)",
    "    at new ManagedUpload (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/s3/managed_upload.js:95:10)",
    "    at features.constructor.upload (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/services/s3.js:1364:20)",
    "    at Runtime.exports.handler (/var/task/index.js:13:10)",
    "    at Runtime.handleOnce (/var/runtime/Runtime.js:66:25)"

Comment: this is the full error and it is continued because it got out of the limit so

Comment: Did you use api gateway? When I use AWS api gateway without turning on the proxy option. I have encountered the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

You should provide `Body` in the `params`.

```
{ Bucket: 'demoupload1', Key: 'userName/', Body: "<sth>"};
```